# Transact SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT MS.idReg, MS.dsMotivo, A.contrato FROM MS
INNER JOIN S 
ON S.motivoSiniestro = MS.idReg
INNER JOIN C
ON C.n__contrat = S.n__contrat
INNER JOIN A
ON A.n__article = C.n__article
```

Table MS has only 12 records, the ones I need and others have many more entries. 
My problem is that I only want the 12 records from MS and their contrato column but I'm getting much more that that. Have tried many combinations of INNER, OUTER, LEFT and RIGHT joins. Any help?

Comment: Did you try `DISTINCT`? Also, are you certain there are no _many_ articles and contracts per MS record?

Comment: You say you want A.contrato in the query.  What if there are many records in A for each record in C, and many records in C for S, and many records in S for MS.  Then which A.contrato should we return?  The max?  The min?  That is why you are getting more than 12 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT MS.idReg, MS.dsMotivo, A.contrato 
FROM dbo.MS
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 A.contrato
    FROM dbo.S
    JOIN dbo.C ON C.n__contrat = S.n__contrat
    JOIN dbo.A ON A.n__article = C.n__article 
    WHERE S.motivoSiniestro = MS.idReg
) s
```

Comment: All those queries return more registries than the ones in MS, because there are distinct combinations of the 3 values..

Answer (score 2):

You get too many records because there are several A.contrato values for each row in the MS table. Sql server does not know which one of all the A.contrato values to take so it returns all of them. First you need to decide which one you want.

If any will do you can simply write your query like this:

```
SELECT MS.idReg, MS.dsMotivo, MAX(A.contrato) 
FROM MS
    INNER JOIN S 
        ON S.motivoSiniestro = MS.idReg
    INNER JOIN C
        ON C.n__contrat = S.n__contrat
    INNER JOIN A
        ON A.n__article = C.n__article
GROUP BY  MS.idReg, MS.dsMotivo
```